How do I set default webpage in web.com for .Net 3.5 server
I am trying to set my default page via web.config on a 3.5 server to default.aspx.  How do I do that?
I cannot find the area in the web.config to insert the following recommendation found elsewhere here:
<defaultDocument>
     <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>

I would appreciate help please.
